# Plot shapefile on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, r-sp

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

map.shp <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)

plot(map.shp)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) + geom_point()
```

How can I put the `map.shp` on the right side of the ggplot as a small inset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are multiple ways to achieve this but a simple way would be to use `cowplot` and `ggdraw`:

I am using `sf` along with `geom_sf` from the development version of `ggplot2` available at `devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)
require(sf)
require(raster)

map.shp <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1) %>% st_as_sf()



plot.cars <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) + geom_point()
plot.map <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data=map.shp)

inset_map <- ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(plot.cars, 0, 0, 1, 1)+
  draw_plot(plot.map, 0.5, 0.52, 0.5, 0.4)
```

[image]

Sorry the shapefile seemed to be rendering really slow for me so couldn't play around with the positioning too much. Is something like this what you were after?

Comment: Yes. This is what I was trying to achieve. Thanks